# JavaScript Array/ Delete a specific object from array/ Add a new object

Tags: javascript, массивы, arraylist, объекты

У меня 3 задания на выполнения для того что бы приняли на *internship* в одной компаний.  Cделать простой `dashboard` и задания к нему:

1. Что бы он отображал список Работников и Клиентов ( с двух созданных `Arrays` );
2. Что бы нажатием на кнопку можно было добавлять одного клиента в список клиентов.
3. Что бы нажатием на кнопку можно было удалить одного работника из списка работников.

Я сделал всё это, но есть одно но, с заданием 3 есть проблемка.
Вычисляю его `employees Index` и удаляю из `Array`, но как удалить из `dashboard` именно его?
Я прикрепил фотки, чтобы было понятно, что именно у меня не получается.

```js
var employees = [
  {
    firstname: "Dorin",
    lastname: "Petrescu"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Sergiu",
    lastname: "Galescu"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Vasile",
    lastname: "Marcu"
  },
];


var customers = [
  {
    firstname: "Valentin",
    lastname: "Condratiuc"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Petru",
    lastname: "Lesco"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Oleg",
    lastname: "Tataru"
  },
];

//1) Display the list of customers and employees
function init(){
  // document.getElementById("names").value = "";
    document.getElementById("names").value = localStorage.getItem("user");
    for ( i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
      var needed_area = document.getElementById("names");
      needed_area.value +="\n"+ customers[i].firstname +" " + customers[i].lastname;
}
}

function init2(){
  for ( i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var selected_area = document.getElementById("names2");
    selected_area.value +="\n"+employees[i].firstname +" " + employees[i].lastname;
  }
}




//2) Delete a Specific Employee

function delete_employee() {
  var delete_item = prompt ("The name of employee you want to delete");
  index = employees.findIndex(x => x.firstname==delete_item);
  console.log(index);
  employees.splice(index, 1);
  var selected_area = document.getElementById("names2");

}




//3) New Customers can be added :
function push_new_customer() {
  var selected_name = prompt("The name of the new customer!");
  var selected_surname = prompt("The surname of the new customer!");
  customers.push({ firstname: selected_name, lastname: selected_surname });
  var needed_area = document.getElementById("names");
  needed_area.value+="\n" +selected_name+ " " +selected_surname;
  // localStorage.setItem("user", needed_area.value);

}
```

```css
    textarea {
      height: 200px;
      width: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="init(); init2();">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2>New Customer</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Registered Customers</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Delete an employee</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Current Employees</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="your name" id="add" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)"> -->
        <button onclick="push_new_customer();" type="button" name="button">Add a new customer!</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea id="names">
        </textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="your name" id="add" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)"> -->
        <button onclick="delete_employee();" type="button" name="button">Delete an employee</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea id="names2">

        </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как правильно писать «чтобы», «что бы» или  «что-бы»?](http://chtoby-pravilno.ru/chtoby/)

Comment: Я не русский, но пытаюсь правильно  написать) но это не так важно, мне бы подсказку по коду)

Comment: а ты не удаляй, ты просто заново выведи все оставшиеся

Comment: @Grundy пробовал что бы он воссоздал заново поле, но он сохраняет предыдущий список, и добавляет уже новый без удаленного, или что-то я неправильно делаю

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то

```
function delete_employee() {
   var delete_item = prompt ("The name of employee you want to delete");
   index = employees.findIndex(x => x.firstname==delete_item);
   console.log(index);
   employees.splice(index, 1);
   var selected_area = document.getElementById("names2");
   selected_area.value = ""; // чистим textarea

   // заполняем заново, как вам писали в комментариях
   for ( i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        selected_area.value +="\n"+employees[i].firstname +" " +  employees[i].lastname;
   }

}
```